# How to check that the docker container is restarted and accessible?

Tags: docker

I have a docker container with JETTY CMD instruction. 
After "docker restart", which goes immediately, I cannot access JETTY about 9-10 seconds. After that time docker container or jetty service is UP again and I can access it.

Question is: is there a standard way to check that the docker container is really up?

Surely I can make a loop with test requests to my service and wait to 200 response code. But maybe there is a more beautiful solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sergey, youre need to use initialization system as supervisor of your in-Docker processes. You may use distro-built-in init systems like systemd/upstart or init.d depends on your OS for checking a container state.

In theory you should to create independent service in you init system on each `docker run` command without `-d` option, because with `-d` option docker detached a container and returned 0 exit status to init system. As result init system lost a control of target process.

For example, realization of this mechanism in Systemd:

1. Create `something.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system`

And type to it something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Simple Blog Rails Docker Container Service
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=on-failure
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker kill simple-blog-rails-container
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/docker rm simple-blog-rails-container
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run simple-blog-rails
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker stop simple-blog-rails-container

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

2. Reload Systemd configuration `systemctl daemon-reload`
3. Just try to run your container by typing `systemctl start something.service` or `restart` instead of start.
4. You can check service state `systemctl status something.service`

For more information about using systemd and docker you may read this CoreOS manual: https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/launching/getting-started-with-systemd/

Comment: Not the easiest solution :)  I will try today. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `docker restart` defaults to a wait time of 10 seconds:

> restart Usage: docker restart [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
>
> Restart a running container
>
> -t, --time=10      Number of seconds to try to stop for before
>   killing the container. Once killed it will then be restarted. Default
>   is 10 seconds.

When I try this with some long running script in a docker container it takes 10 seconds before it's done. If I change the command line to use a different timeout (like `-t=4`} it comes back in 4 seconds.

If you want to determine if a container is running (even if your service contained within it is not quite ready yet) you can:

1. Run `docker ps` - which will give you a list of all running docker
   containers
2. Use the Docker Remote API command `GET /containers/json` - this will
   give you a json response with a list of running containers.

https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.16/

https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#ps

Answer (score 0):

[uptime-kuma](https://github.com/louislam/uptime-kuma)
or
[statping-ng](https://github.com/statping-ng/statping-ng)
should help